# C# HttpWebRequest и UserAgent

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Использую следующий код для получения ответа от сервера при помощи `HttpWebRequest` (код сокращён до минимума, захардкоден и используется только в качестве примера):

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/vector-electronics/VME64E02P01/6819140");

        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, @"gzip, deflate, br");
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.9");
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9";
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

        request.Method = "GET";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36";

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Проблема заключается в следующем: если я использую User-Agent, то от сайта возвращается ошибка "Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (403) Запрещено". При этом, если закомментировать строку, где происходит присвоение User-Agent, то сайт успешно возвращает ответ. User-Agent используется из последней версии хрома. Также я провёл тест в Zennoposter, который отправляет GET-запрос с User-Agent в заголовках и подобных проблем не наблюдается.
Это какой-то баг .NET или я что-то упускаю?

Comment: Посмотрите разницу в заголовках там и тут. Может, вы что-то не отправляете из того, что нужно серверу.

Comment: HttpWebRequest устарел, используйте HttpClient.

Comment: Полностью копировал заголовки из браузера, а также из Zennoposter. Не хочет работать с User-Agent. При этом, если вписать в User-Agent текст из головы, то сайт принимает без проблем

Comment: Еще раз, вы используете технологию тех времен, когда я еще был маленький и не умел программировать. Черт его знает, что внутри этого древнего как мир клиента происходит. Смените технологию на актуальную. С большой вероятностью оно заработает как должно без дополнительных танцев. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Сменил уже кучу библиотек и технологий: xNet.dll, WebClient и только, что HttpClient. Ошибка всё та же. С юзер-агентом не работает, без него работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpWebRequest` устарел, используйте `HttpClient`.

У меня работает без ошибок

```cs
class Program
{
    static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All });

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.ParseAdd("gzip, deflate, br");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.ParseAdd("en-US,en;q=0.9");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");

        try
        {
            string response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/vector-electronics/VME64E02P01/6819140");
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
            
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

В консоль выводится очень большой HTML документ.

---

Методом проб и ошибок выяснили, что на .NET Framework 4.7.2 проблема есть,  а на .NET 5 - нет. Видимо все-таки в `HttpRequestHandler` есть баги (или какие-то причуды сервера) и `SocketsHttpHandler` работает лучше.

---

Еще выяснили, что для фреймворка помогло `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");`

Comment: А вот у меня по-прежнему ошибка и с вашим кодом. А у вас какая система и версия VS?

Comment: @ГалицкийОлег Windows 10 / VS 2019 / .NET 5, а у вас?

Comment: Если убрать строку с установкой юзер-агента ваш код работает. С ним не работает. При чём, сейчас пробовал устанавливать различные юзер-агенты и всё безуспешно. Как будто что-то у меня на ноуте не то. Идеи подходят к завершению... Другие сайты всегда работали без проблем, а вот сегодня натолкнулся на это "чудо"

Comment: @ГалицкийОлег какая версия системы и под какую версию дотнета проект?

Comment: win10/vs2019/.Net Framework 4.7.2

Comment: @ГалицкийОлег ради теста попробуйте Core 3.1 или .NET 5. Там другой более крутой сетевой движок. Я сейчас уже не за компом, не смогу протестить на старом фреймворке. Завтра если только.

Comment: Да, под Core 3.1 работает без проблем

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124640/discussion-between---and-aepot).

Comment: А вот и не баг... Достаточно проанализировать трафик. Подсказка: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");`

Comment: Устанавливал я этот заголовок и ничего не дал он мне

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а вот это прикол, спасибо.

Comment: @ГалицкийОлег А это не решение, это "проблемное место". Указанный вами сайт не пускает к себе, если установить заголовок [Connection](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection), без разницы какое там будет значение. А `HttpWebRequest` (и наверно старые версии `HttpClient` в .Net Framework) его добавляет по умолчанию. Вот теперь и думайте, как от него избавиться.

Comment: Кстати, для HttpClient действительно помогло. Для HttpWebRequest - нет. Этот заголовок только через свойство KeepAlive менять можно и только на true/false.
Спасибо вам!

Comment: @ГалицкийОлег Интересно, как вам "помогло" это... Я лично не смог их убрать, что в старом `HttpClient`, что в `HttpWebRequest`. В любом случае, установите этому заголовку какую либо белеберду, сайту это нравиться) Например: `request.Connection = "asdasda";` для `HttpWebRequest` и тоже самое для `HttpClient` - `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "adasda");`.

Comment: Мне помогло, я добавил ваш код и всё заработало:
`client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ дописал в ответ, чтобы было.

Comment: Я понял как помогло.... `HttpClient` очень классно обрабатывает заголовки, делая `Connection: Keep-Alive,Keep-Alive`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ жесть какая-то :) это ведь речь про HttpRequestHandler?))

Comment: @EvgeniyZ странно, ведь обычный браузер тоже этот заголовок по умолчанию добавляет. Может дело в регистре `keep-alive`. Сервер странный, чем черт не шутит.

Comment: @aepot Что именно? `Keep-Alive,Keep-Alive`? Я не знаю кто так делает, что `HttpWebRequest` при добавлении заголовка `.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Connection, "Keep-Alive");` будет дублировать его, не переписывая старое значение, `HttpClient` делает тоже самое. `Может дело в регистре` - нет, проверил, ему именно не нравится заведомо стандартные значения `keep-alive` и `close``Сервер странный` - а мне кажется не странный, а хз, новый, ибо по ссылке выше можно заметить замечание про `HTTP/2`, может в этом дело? В любом случае, `.Net5` не шлет и слава богу)

Comment: И я повторю вопрос. Почему при стандартном keep-alive, но без юзер-агента у меня всё работает. Также работало, когда я назначал юзер-агенту значение "Test". Можно было бы конечно оставить без юзера и в принципе подставить клиента, но это будет непрофессионально.

Comment: @ГалицкийОлег если кратко, причуда сервера. Если подробно, то отсутствие заголовка скорее всего что-то ломает в сервере и он не глючит с keep-alive. Быть модет что-то еще другое.

Comment: @aepot скорее всего ничего не ломается, просто на сервере может быть условие, определяющее для каких юзер-агентов включать keep-alive, а для каких нет.